# How to return this valid json data in Python?

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

I tested using Python to translate a curl to get some data.

```
import requests
import json

username="abc"
password="123"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
params = (
    ('version', '2017-05-01'),
)

data = '{"text":["This is message one."], "id":"en-es"}'
response = requests.post('https://somegateway.service/api/abc', headers=headers, params=params, data=data, auth=(username, password))
print(response.text)
```

The above works fine. It returns json data.
It seems ["This is message one."] is a list. I want to use a variable that loads a file to replace this list.
I tried:

```
with open(f,"r",encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    file_in_list=fp.read().splitlines()
    toStr=str(file_in_list)
    data = '{"text":'+toStr+', "id":"en-es"}'
    response = requests.post('https://somegateway.service/api/abc', headers=headers, params=params, data=data, auth=(username, password))
    print(response.text)
```

But it returned error below.

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "error" : "Mapping error, invalid JSON"
}
```

Can you help? How can I have valid response.text?

Thanks.

**update:**

The content of f contains only five lines below:

```
This is message one.
this is 2.
this is three.
this is four.
this is five.
```

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out how to format a JSON string, why not just create a dict and JSON-encode it? For example: `data = {"text": file_in_list, "id": "en-us"}`, then you can either post `json.dumps(encode)`, or use a method that does the JSON encoding for you.

Comment: Use `[toStr]` instead of just `toStr` when you read the file content?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla That doesn't make any sense. You can't concatenate a list to a string. Even if you could, why would you expect it to help? He's already got the string representation of a list of strings; why would a list of the string representation of a list be useful?

Comment: As a side note, consider `list(fp)` (or `fp.readlines()`) instead of `fp.read().splitlines()`. The way you've written it works, but only by reading the whole file into one giant string, then splitting that string into separate lines. But if you don't call `read()`, the file is already an iterable of lines, so Python can read it in a line at a time and build up the list without wasting that time and memory.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry, it looks like I did oversee `.splitlines()`, I was under the impression that the OP's server side API needs a `list` but is instead sending just a `str` instead of a `list of strings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your existing code fails is that `str` applied to a list of strings will only rarely give you valid JSON. They're not intended to do the same thing. JSON only allows double-quoted strings; Python allows both single- and double-quoted strings. And, unless your strings all happen to include `'` characters, Python will render them with single quotes:

```
>>> print(["abc'def"]) # gives you valid JSON, but only by accident
["abc'def"]
>>> print(["abc"]) # does not give you valid JSON
['abc']
```

If you want to get the valid JSON encoding of a list of strings, don't try to trick `str` into giving you valid JSON by accident, just use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
toStr = json.dumps(file_in_list)
```

---

But, even more simply, you shouldn't be trying to figure out how to construct JSON strings in the first place. Just create a dict and `json.dumps` the whole thing:

```
data = {"text": file_in_list, "id": "en-es"}
data_str = json.dumps(data)
```

Being able to do this is pretty much the whole point of JSON: it's a simple way to automatically serialize all of the types that are common to all the major scripting languages.

---

Or, even better, let `requests` do it for you by passing a `json` argument instead of a `data` argument:

```
data = {"text": file_in_list, "id": "en-es"}
response = requests.post('https://somegateway.service/api/abc', headers=headers, params=params, json=data, auth=(username, password))
```

This also automatically takes care of setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` for you. You weren't doing that—and, while many servers will accept your input without it, it's illegal, and some servers will not allow it.

---

For more details, see the section [More complicated POST requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) in the `requests` docs. But there really aren't many more details.

Answer (score -1):

## tldr;

`toStr = json.dumps(file_in_list)`

## Explanation

Assuming your file contains something like 

`String_A
String_B`

You need to ensure that toStr is:

1. Enclosed by `[` and `]`
2. Every String in the list is enclosed by quotation marks.

So your raw json (as a String) is equal to `'{"text":["String_A", "String_B"], "id":"en-es"}'`

Comment: if I remove toStr=str(file_in_list) and change to 
data = '{"text":'+file_in_list+', "id":"en-es"}', 

it returned another error 
data = '{"text":'+file_in_list+', "id":"en-es"}'
TypeError: must be str, not list